# Copy files matching both sub directories and file names from strings in file

Tags: bash, copy

I want to copy files from multiple sub directories to a new directory within the main directory called `copiedFiles/`. I only want to copy files that can be matched to strings in the file `strs2bMatchd.csv`. The names of the sub directories also matches the first part of the strings to be matched (see example below).

The main directory with sub directories looks like this

```
main_dir/
strs2bMatchd.csv
    1111/
      1111_aaa1_x873.csv
      1111_aaa2_x874.csv
      1111_ddd1_x443.csv
      1111_ddd2_x444.csv
    1112/
      1112_bbb1_x912.csv
      1112_bbb2_x913.csv
      1112_fff1_x664.csv
      1112_fff2_x665.csv
    1113/
      1113_ccc1_x912.csv
      1113_ccc2_x913.csv
```

The files to be copied should match the strings in `strs2bMatchd.csv` file

```
cat strs2bMatchd.csv
1111_aaa1
1111_aaa2
1112_bbb1
1112_bbb2
1113_ccc1
1113_ccc2
```

This is the expected result

```
main_dir/
strs2bMatchd.csv
    1111/
      1111_aaa1_x873.csv
      1111_aaa2_x874.csv
      1111_ddd1_x443.csv
      1111_ddd2_x444.csv
    1112/
      1112_bbb1_x912.csv
      1112_bbb2_x913.csv
      1112_fff1_x664.csv
      1112_fff2_x665.csv
    1113/
      1113_ccc1_x912.csv
      1113_ccc2_x913.csv
    copiedFiles/
      1111_aaa1_x873.csv
      1111_aaa2_x874.csv
      1112_bbb1_x912.csv
      1112_bbb2_x913.csv
      1113_ccc1_x912.csv
      1113_ccc2_x913.csv
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: `cd main_dir && mkdir copiedFiles && sed 's/_.*//' strs2bMatchd.csv | sort -u | xargs find | grep -Ff strs2bMatchd.csv | xargs cp -t copiedFiles`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, consider

```
M=main_dir
mkdir -p $M/copiedFiles
find $M  | grep -F -v "$M/copiedFiles" | grep -Ff $M/strs2bMatch.csv  | xargs cp -t $M/copiedFiles/
```

It will execute the find once.

If the files may contain space or other special characters, consider using the safe version (NUL terminated strings) - for find (-print0), grep (-z -Z) xargs (-0).

Update 1: OP indicate his version of cp does not have -t. Alternative solution, without this options is posted.

I can not test, please try to solve problem using man, etc.

```
M=main_dir
mkdir -p $M/copiedFiles
find $M  | grep -F -v "$M/copiedFiles" | grep -Ff $M/strs2bMatch.csv  | xargs -I{} cp {} $M/copiedFiles/
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. When trying it, I get ```cp: illegal option -- t
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory```

Comment: @jO.  What Is your os/version. Must be old, as -t was added few years ago to most distributions ? I will attempt to revise.